# Can jinja2 replace values in a properties file?

Tags: python, jinja2

Say you have a yaml like this:

```
foo: {{foo}}
bar: {{bar}}
```

where foo and bar are variables past in as runtime arguments.

Is jinja2 something that can replace these or should I be looking elsewhere?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. Jinja is just a templating language: it takes a template, substitutes variables for their values, and produces output. Does that do what you need?